# Jquery Cross-domain Problem when try a put reques in

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain-policy

I try to make a PUT request on JQUERY to a RESTFULL service, when try make the request to url with localhost (http://localhost/Domain) the request work. But when change the url to some ip (http://192.123.32.3) the operation on the server don't fire.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: urlOperation,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: $.toJSON(submitVote),        success: function (result) 
    {
      alert('Great ...');

    }
});
```

### The error on chrome are  'Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods'

I've try solve this adding the put permission on Application_beginRequest event something like that :

```
private void EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

After read the jquery.Ajax documention I've try added the property crossDomain='true' without sucess.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will do everything it can to block cross-domain requests.  You can use an iframe for ajax requests or you could also use the server the page is running on to proxy the request for you.

Hope that helps, maybe you can check how jQuery handles crossDomain='true', if there isn't an iframe involved it just won't work on all browsers.

Comment: I'm wondering why I can make a 'POST' request  but when try 'PUT' what the difference for cross domain problem!!?

Comment: PUT is in the HTTP protocol as defined by W3C, I'm not really sure what to tell you.  I've also heard issues of many individuals getting cross-domain requests to work on all browsers except Chrome.